# Is there a better way to make a wait command? Cause importing time and then sleep seems to cause my hold script to sleep rather than just one line

Tags: sleep

importing time and then sleep seems to cause all of my scripts to sleep rather than just the one line. I was asking if there was a better way to call a wait. A new import entirely would also work.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can’t get your question clearly but in nodejs and angularjs , not to wait for all scripts to execute or sleep all scripts. Which scripts you want to wait for results then those are added to promise. Nodejs and angularjs are synchronous,so to make asynchronous, we use await-promise.It holds only those scripts which return results waiting for other scripts to process.